# How can I determine why my Racket code runs so slowly?

Tags: performance, racket

Just for fun, I wrote a quick Racket command-line script to parse old Unix fortune files.  Fortune files are just giant text files, with a single `%` on a blank line separating entries.

Just as a quick first hack, I wrote the following Racket code:

```
(define fortunes
    (with-input-from-file "fortunes.txt"
      (λ ()
        (regexp-split #rx"%" (port->string)))))
```

I thought it would run nearly instantly.  Instead, it takes a very long time to run—on the order of a couple of minutes.  In comparison, what I think of as equivalent Python:

```
with open('fortunes.txt') as f:
    fortunes = f.read().split('%')
```

executes immediately, with equivalent results to the Racket code.

What am I doing wrong here?  Yes, there's some obvious low-hanging fruit, such as I'm sure that things would be better if I didn't slurp the whole file into RAM with `port->string`, but the behavior is so pathologically bad I feel as if I must be doing something stupid at a much higher level than that.

Is there a more Racket-like way to do this with equivalently better performance? Is Racket I/O really poor for some operations? Is there some way to profile my code slightly deeper than the naïve profiler in DrRacket so I can figure out what *about* a given line is causing a problem?

**EDIT**: The fortunes file I'm using is FreeBSD's as found at http://fortunes.cat-v.org/freebsd/, which weighs in at about 2 MB.  The best runtime for Racket 5.1.3 x64 on OS X Lion was:

```
real    1m1.479s
user    0m57.400s
sys     0m0.691s
```

For Python 2.7.1 x64, it was:

```
real    0m0.057s
user    0m0.029s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Eli's right that the time is being spent almost entirely in `regexp-split` (although a full second appears to be spent in `port->string`), but it's not clear to me that there's a preferred yet equally simple method.

Comment: I just tried your code using `"/usr/share/games/fortunes/work"` (105 KB) instead of `"fortunes.txt"` and it took less than a tenth of a second. How big is `"fortunes.txt"`, and what platform are you running on?

Comment: It's the ~2 MB fortunes file from FreeBSD; you can grab it at http://fortunes.cat-v.org/freebsd/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed in the latest Git HEAD version of Racket, see: [github.com/plt/racket/commit/8eefaba](http://github.com/plt/racket/commit/8eefaba). Your example now runs in 0.1 seconds for me.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like most of the cost is  due to running `regexp-split` on a string.  The fastest alternative that I found was splitting a byte-string, then converting the results to a strings:

```
(map bytes->string/utf-8
     (call-with-input-file "db"
       (λ (i) (regexp-split #rx#"%" (port->bytes i)))))
```

With a random fortune DB of ~2MB, your code takes about 35s, and this version takes 33ms.

(I'm not sure why it takes so long on a string, yet, but it's definitely way too slow.)

**EDIT**: We tracked it to an efficiency bug. Rough description: when Racket does a `regexp-match` on a string, it will convert large parts of the string to a byte string (in UTF-8) for the search. This function is the core one that is implemented in C. `regexp-split` uses it repeatedly to find all of the matches, and therefore keeps re-doing this conversion. I'm looking at a way to do things better, but until it's fixed, use the above workaround.

Comment: Maybe file a bug report with Racket?

Comment: I'm not yet clear it's a bug per se.  E.g., Squeak's pure-Smalltalk regex library only fares moderately better, but there's a split method on `String` that's faster than the Python I gave above.  I just don't see anything like a `string-split` or `sequence-split` function that might be faster—but I'm totally open to that just being me not finding docs, which is why I asked.

Comment: Benjamin: We tracked it to an efficiency bug.  Rough description: when Racket does a `regexp-match` on a string, it will convert large parts of the string to a byte string (in UTF-8) for the search.  This function is the core one that is implemented in C.  `regexp-split` uses it repeatedly to find all of the matches, and therefore keeps re-doing this conversion.  I'm looking at a way to do things better, but until it's fixed, use the above workaround.

Comment: This is now fixed in the latest Git HEAD version of Racket, see: https://github.com/plt/racket/commit/8eefaba , which now runs your example in 0.1 seconds for me.